# Vertices coordinates in graph-tool

Tags: python, performance, pandas, graph, graph-tool

I'd like to specify the coordinates of the vertices of a graph in graph-tool in an efficient way.

Given a csv which looks like:

```
Node,X,Y

1,2.5,3.8

2,3.4,2.9
```

...

I'd like graph-tool to plot vertex 1 at position (2.5,3.8) etc...

A non efficient solution is given in :
[Explicit vertex position in python graph-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704281/explicit-vertex-position-in-python-graph-tool#) , so I can basically use a for loop over all my coordinates and save them in the property map 'pos'. If my graph is 'g' and my csv is read using pandas in the dataframe 'coordinates', I can do:

```
for i in range(1,numnodes+1):
    pos[g.vertex(i)] = (coordinates.values[i-1,1],coordinates.values[i-1,2])
```

The problem is that my number of nodes, numnodes is big (~10^7), and this can take some time.

Is there a more efficient way to do this operation by inputting directly the data in the property map 'pos' ?

Comment: Can you try to use it in vectorized manner: `pos = coordinates[['X','Y']].values` instead of looping? I don't know `graph-tool` module, but i guess it should be able to work with numpy arrays or maybe even with pandas data frames...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question, an efficient way to do this is to use the .set_2d_array() function;

```
pos.set_2d_array(coordinates[['X','Y']].values.T)
```

does the trick.
 Here ".T" is the transposition function, part of the numpy library.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
pos = coordinates[['X','Y']].values
```

if `graph-tool` accepts numpy arrays, otherwise:

```
pos = [tuple(t) for t in coordinates[['X','Y']].values]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately both didn't work, I suspect it is because 'pos' looses its type when doing this operation.
For example, if I do
     for e in pos:
     print e
I get
     array([ 2.5,  3.8])
     array([ 3.4,  2.9])
     ...